# How to include auto-numbered lists in github_document?

Tags: r, r-markdown

The below code works for auto-numbering lists in plain html:

```
---
title: "Assignment 1"
output: 
  html_document:
    number_sections: true
---

1. First

2. second
```

but how can I use auto-numbering to output a `github_document`?

UPDATE: this works for me after updating to `pandoc 2.2.3.2` and RMarkdown `1.10` not sure if there are other ways

```
---
title: "Assignment 1"
output: github_document
---

#. First

#. second
```

Comment: It is not possible, see the `--number-sections` option of the `pandoc` documentation: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers

Comment: Your example is to minimal. Do you want to number lists or sections?

Comment: @RalfStubner lists (I put it in the title)

Comment: Then please extend your example with a list to make it "complete".