# How to disable automatic list numbering in github documents?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

Last month I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071256/how-to-include-auto-numbered-lists-in-github-document?noredirect=1#comment89145239_51071256) on how to do automating numbering in Rmarkdown github documents, and I was pointed to the documentation where it says it's not available. Now I found out it somewhat works, but not as I would expect. For instance:

````
---
title: "test 3"
output: github_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

9. Fruits

   - Apple
   - Orange
   - Banana

10. More fruits

11. and more fruits

1. Hey!
````

Returns this:

[image]
However, I don't want the numbering to restart after the bullet list. How do I avoid automatic numbering?

Comment: I get different output from your example: Items are numbered 9 to 12. The bullet list is indented. Which `rmarkdown` and `pandoc` version do you use?

Comment: sorry I updated the pic. RMarkdown 1.10 pandoc 1.19.2.1

Comment: I also use `rmarkdown` 1.10. And I can reproduce the issue using `pandoc` 1.17.2. I cannot reproduce it using `pandoc` version 2.2.1.

Comment: BTW, what you observe is standard behaviour for markdown, c.f. https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#ordered-lists. I am not sue why the `startnum` extension, which changes this behaviour, is activated only with the newer pandoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bullet list  is not indented in the PDF, indicating that the list isn't recognized as a sublist. This is most likely due to the four spaces rule, which was strictly enforced in older pandoc versions. Adding another space to the bullet list's indentation should fix the issue.

Item counting restarts if top-level blocks are inserted between items. This can be used to force a restart, e.g. by adding an empty HTML comment:

```
11. and more fruits

<!-- -->
1. Hey!
```